# Android trial program with same codebase as full version

Tags: android, demo, trialware

I have a application already in Android Market. I want to create a trial application that is based on the same code base and then add some new code to limit some key features. Is there any good tutorials, blogs, stack posts, etc. that discuss how to do this in eclipse with one code base to maintain.

One of the problems that I am having is when I access resources in the code you have to reference them such as packageName.R.whatever and two apps cannot have the same packageName. So my trial version could not reuse the code base because all the resource references would not work. Has anyone found ways around these issues? I have tried a lot of searching but am not coming up with a lot of answers.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need to do some refactoring, but hopefully not too much. Create a common code base, and place that code in an Android Library project. Then use that project from the full version, and from the trial version. Your library project can hopefully contain most of your code.

Comment: Agreed. Moving the common code to a library project is your best bet. I've done exactly that before. Here's the official documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

Comment: So question about that. Can a library have its own resources? I.E. will it fix my problem with the resource names being project specific. Can they now be library specific.

Comment: A library project can have resources.